# Scrolling to top while on a call?

Tags: ios, macos

Normally when you press the top status bar on the iPhone, it will scroll the main list component all the to the top. When you are on a call, though, the status bar becomes a bit bigger and when you click it, it goes to the phone app. Is there any way to scroll all the way up on whatever page you are looking at without having to manually drag the page while you are on a phone call?

Comment: A good question, since the most frequent action I perform when on a call is to look up contact info for someone else, which typically involves scrolling to the top of the contact list so I can use the search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the functionality replaces the tap for scrolling with a tap to resume the call.

You might instead need to use spotlight to search for the contact rather than scrolling in the case you mention. Worst case is you can use the paging / "scrubbing" gesture to tap and then scroll vertically along the side of the contact application to rapidly scroll to the desired letter. For apps without this added functionalities, you must scroll or end the call and then obtain the information you need before resuming the conversation.

[image: scrubbing in the contacts app]

Comment: Bet you have a hard time keeping track of all your Dan's... Anyway I'll just mention that this same issue also plagues the interface when tethering is active (the bar becomes blue and takes you to "Personal Hotspot")

Comment: Indeed - and don't get me started about mike :)